# id contains specific string name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a tmp variable. If a tag id contains tmp string want to addClass. How to do?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var tmp = "#lnkPage" + id;

   $("#pageingdiv").children().each(function (n, i) {
        var id = this.id;
      //if (id.contains(tmp)) {
       // $(id).addClass('box');
        //}
    });
 });

 <div id="pageingDiv">
        <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage1" ></a>
        <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage2" ></a>
        <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage3" ></a>
        <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage4" ></a>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), [Attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and [Attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) Selectors. They will help you select all the elements you want directly without the need to call any other functions than `.addClass()`. :)

Comment: I just wanted to write the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

use `indexOf()`

```
if(id.indexOf(tmp) !== -1)
{
    $(id).addClass('box');
}
```

Moreover you should not have elements with same ID, you should use class instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery( "input[id*='value']" )` Selector to check if its contain specific string as ID.

**Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $( "a[id*='lnkPage']" ).addClass('SampleClass');
    });

</script>


<div id="pageingDiv">
    <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage1" ></a>
    <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage1" ></a>
    <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage1" ></a>
    <a id="CPH_Content_C002_lnkPage1" ></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var tmp = "lnkPage1";
$("a[id*='"+tmp+"']").addClass('box');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var tmp = "lnkPage" + id; // <-----remove the hash '#'

 $('[id$="'+tmp+'"]').addClass('box');
```